# Page Got Stuck When Service Call Angular 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I'm calling service in `ngOnIt()`. When I route the page so page got stuck till  data loads complete because it takes 5 to 10 second to load the data from WebAPI. I'm unable to click any other buttons or textbox.

html

```
<ngx-slick class="row-2 vSlides" #slickModal="slick-modal" [config]="slideConfig">
              <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let noti of objNotifications" class="vSlide row-2 slide">
                <h4><a href="#" [innerHTML]="noti.Title"></a></h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span [innerHTML]="noti.DDate"></span></li>
                  <li><i class="fa fa-university"></i> <span [innerHTML]="noti.ParentDeptName"></span></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="skeleton-loader" id="skeleton-loader1">
                <img src="../../../assets/img/skeleton-loader.gif">
                <img src="../../../assets/img/skeleton-loader.gif" style="margin-top: 10px;">
              </div>
            </ngx-slick>
```

component.ts

```
objNotifications: DepartmentsNotificationsModel[];
constuctor(private departmentService: DepartmentsService){}
ngOnInit(){
this.notificationsService();
}
 notificationsService() {
    this.departmentService.GetAllNotifications().subscribe(res => {
      this.objNotifications = res as DepartmentsNotificationsModel[];
      $('#skeleton-loader1').hide();

    });
  }
```

service.ts

```
 readonly baseUri = "url";
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    objNotifications: DepartmentsNotificationsModel[];
    GetAllNotifications() {
        return this.http.get(this.baseUri + "urlParameters").map(res => this.objNotifications = res as DepartmentsNotificationsModel[]);
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a working sample stackblitz replicating this issue?

Comment: I haven't. It's happen in my project